# Can I integrate Solr with Sharepoint with out using Lucene Connector Framework

Tags: sharepoint, lucene, solr, connector

Can I integrate Solr with Sharepoint with out using Lucene Connector Framework.
if so should I make Solr Index the Sharepoint's underlying  database ? Will this produce successful search results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get text into Solr, you need to be able to extract it. The Lucene Connector Framework is meant to do just that. If you somehow get the raw text another way, you may use the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to import information. If you index text correctly, and configure the schema well, you should be able to get successful search results.

Comment: Where does Apache Tika filter fit in here ?

Comment: I am not sure that it does. Looking at Tika's supported document formats: http://tika.apache.org/formats.html, it does support several Microsoft document formats. I do not know which of these are relevant to Sharepoint. Ideally, Tika lets you extract text and meta-data out of a file in a supported format, so you can tailor the repository handling (file system, directories, crawling) yourself. But why not use the LCF?

Comment: Yes i went ahead with using LCF,will LCF take care of full text search ?

Comment: AFAIU, LCF handles getting the text into Lucene or Solr.
From there on, you need to handle the searches yourself, which is not hard (I guess easier with Solr, as most things are).
See this presentation about LCF from a talk given last week:
http://lucene-eurocon.org/slides/Lucene-Connectors-Framework-Introduction_Karl-Wright.pdf

Comment: apache tika poorly parses out useful fields from html sharepoint format. works nicely on many pages, but not sharepoint.